# Is it possible to mock SimpleUploadedFile?

Tags: python, django, mocking

I have a function like this:

```py
def my_func():
    [...]
    with open(full_path, "rb") as file:
        image.image = SimpleUploadedFile(
            name=image.external_url,
            content=file.read(),
            content_type="image/jpeg",
         )
        image.save()
    print(f"{file_name} - Saved!")
```

I would like mock the "SimpleUploadedFile" for a test (calling print...).

Is it possible?

A little bit of context: the function download and upload files. Maybe the test is not necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `SimpleUploadedFile` is defined in the module `a` and the function `my_func()` is defined in the module `b`.

The test file can be defined as the following:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from b import my_func

def func_only_print():
    # assign an image to some_image
    some_image = ...
    print("This function substitutes SimpleUploadedFile")
    return some_image

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_my_func(self):
         # note in the patch the string 'a.SimpleUploadedFile' => SimpleUploadedFile is defined in 'a' 
         with patch('a.SimpleUploadedFile') as mock_SimpleUploadedFile:
             mock_SimpleUploadedFile.side_effect = func_only_print
             my_func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If you execute the test file you might to see the message `"This function substitutes SimpleUploadedFile"` printed on the standard output.